# I changed boot sequence but computer still boots to windows

Tags: boot-failure

I put the Ubuntu .iso file onto a USB drive. I went into BIOS. I changed the boot sequence to put "removable device" first. I did everything the page asked me to do, but the computer did not seem to recognize there was anything else but Windows when I restarted the computer. Is there something else besides the iso file that I need?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use http://www.linuxliveusb.com/ to make bootable usb disk

Comment: I can confirm, this is best tool to make bootable USB.

Comment: @zero i think this guy didnt excract iso to usb . i think he only put iso to usb

Comment: Thank you all for your response. Enes is right. I just copied the iso to the usb, which didn't seem to make sense, but that is what is on this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick    I probably misinterpreted "Put Ubuntu onto your USB flash drive" as "copy and paste" Yesterday I discovered UNetbootin, which installed Ubuntu onto my usb. I successfully booted today, much to my delight.

Comment: can you confirm my answer if it is true @Paul

Comment: yes, your answer is true. I did not extract iso to usb. I just copied and pasted. It is also true that I needed to use linuxlive or UNetbootin to make a bootable usb disk. This thread might seem obvious to some, but there are probably going to be quite a few new people like me who have this problem, so maybe it will be of help to them.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want another way of choosing boot device, usually holding F12 when your computers starting up will open the boot menu that you can select your USB from, just a little faster than going into BIOS.

Other than that, what Enes said.